# I cannot click a button/element when the css of the element contains only an ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, robotframework

I am attempting to click a button using Robot Framework - Selenium.
The element of the button looks like this:

```
<div id="isc_7A" eventproxy="addButton" onfocus="isc.EH.focusInCanvas(addButton_label,true);" onblur="if(window.isc)isc.EH.blurFocusCanvas(addButton_label,true);" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: 6px; top: 1px; width: 65px; height: 22px; z-index: 201603; overflow: visible; cursor: pointer;" onscroll="return addButton.$lh()">
    <div id="isc_79" eventproxy="addButton" style="position: relative; visibility: inherit; z-index: 201603; cursor: pointer;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1" height="22">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="true" class="stretchImgButton" align="center" valign="center" tabindex="-1" onfocus="addButton_label.$47()">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="stretchImgButton" style="margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;background-image:none;background-color:transparent;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;font-size:1px;padding-right:6px"><img src="https://hq-foxtrot-s1.hq-foxtrot.defencetest.local:10006/journal/images/tag_new.png" width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle" name="isc_79addButton_label$4u" style="vertical-align:middle" eventpart="icon" border="0" suppress="TRUE"></td>
                                    <td class="stretchImgButton" style="margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;background-image:none;background-color:transparent;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;" nowrap="true">New Tag</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My tests in PyCharm looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Create a new tag
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
This is some basic info about the test
    [Documentation]  This is some basic info about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser  [website]  chrome
    Sleep  10sec
    wait until page contains element  css=#isc_7A
    click button  css=#isc_7A
```

I've also tried using the xpath of the element, but still no success. The xpath looks like this:

```
//*[@id="isc_7A"]
```

Comment: What happens when you run that test just saying "no success" isn't enough. Does it throw an error? Does it click the wrong element? Something else?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please post the html screenshot of the div.

Comment: These id values look like autogenerated - if so, they'd be unreliable to be used in locators. Also, you're targeting the div element - are you sure the event handler is attached to it, vs the img one?

Comment: This id is dynamically generated and I assume it's SmartClient. You should use other attributes or combination of attributes using xpath.

Comment: Test the locator in the browser, does it change each time you refresh the page? Have you tried an alternate locator like the CSS selector, `div[eventproxy='addButton']`?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley
The error showing is 'Element with locator '#isc_7A' not found.'.
Some error is displayed even when using the xpath instead of css

Comment: @Todor Minakov
I really don't know...not that good at looking into code, just trying my best learning to automate few things

Comment: @JaPyR
I have tried, but it does not seem to work either

Comment: @JeffC
No it does not change after refresh. The only thing that I've seen changing is the 'class="stretchImgButton"' into 'class="stretchImgButtonOver"' every time I hover the mouse onver the button.
I have tried with css, xpath and even with the raw element....still not results

Comment: Any chance the site is publicly accessible?

Comment: @TodorMinakov
Unfortunately not :(